# Interactive CSS for all types of screen

Tags: php, html, css, interactive

I am trying to make my website fully interactive.

**First issue:** Logo img is not vertically aligned as I want it.

If the screen width is >1200, the margin from the top (nav) is too big. It appears like that :

[image]

If the screen width is less it appears as I want it :

[image]

I tried to change padding and margin but with no result for all the screen sizes. I am thinking that this could be a good idea :

```
    .homepage #logo {
        margin-top: -10%;
    }
```

but I don't think it is a good practice.

**Second issue:** I have 4 boxes. I made them interactive. I even made the image size interactive thanks to stackoverflow users. So when the screen width is more than 736px it looks like that :

[image]

but if it is less, the image is really big :

[image]

As a reference here is the link : [enter link description here](http://apolosiskos.co.uk/apolo.html)
Feel free to ask any CSS. Cheers

Comment: you can set more stuff besides width in your media queries...

Comment: how can I make their size (including the image and the text) interactive  ---  by putting a `font-size` element in your media queries for each size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, edit your css sheet to add the responsive image css I posted about.Then save [this text document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3ag1kDXpLflTVF4d19wZk4xU00) that I made for 2 to 4 responsive grids

Use the html in the various spots and copy all the css to your stylesheet.

Comment: Next I would go to https://realfavicongenerator.net/ and create all the different favicons that will work on every device. Upload a 260px X 250px image. It then creates all the various sizes and give you the html code to use.

Comment: I saved your text for future reference. My boxes look fine now although I have not used your code there. I just added a max-width for the image when the screen width is less than 736px. 

Also, I managed to solve the gap issue. As for the small gap issue I added a padding-top:10% to "hi-icon" and "workcontainer" divs.

Why did you mention the favicon thing? I already have a favicon and it looks fine.

Comment: The favicon generator makes about 24 icons and a few code files. You upload them all to the root directory, For example, you have one favicon. This means it won't show on some devices and will show incorrectly on others. Look at the favicon checker [link]https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?site=http%3A%2F%2Fapolosiskos.co.uk%2Fapolo.html#.VwuruUfPSSo    for details for your site.  Edit your favicon to be 256px X 256px and then upload it to the generator, It spits out all the new files in a few min,

Answer (score 1):

you have some 
[html errors](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fapolosiskos.co.uk%2Findex3.php)

you have a lot of css errors
[css validator errors](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapolosiskos.co.uk%2Findex3.php&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)

I'd clean up your code with those links and then save and view your page again. It looks like you have the grid sytem setup in your css.

Comment: The CSS you are seeing is for the full webpage. I attached the link of the div I want to make better. I will give my best this days. It is my hobby so I don't have much time. But I want to make it work. For every device :)

Comment: I love this responsive grid generator. Try it     http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/

Comment: Amazing tool ! Thank you. I will use that. I will try to clean the CSS and HTML when I can and I will come back to update the question as there are many issues. I think my problem is that I have to make the img in the box responsive. And then it should work.

Comment: css for responsive images  `img{width:100%!important;height:auto!important;}`

Comment: I have udated the question mate.

Comment: Sorry, I went away for the weekend. You still have a load of css errors and html errors. Go to the links I posted a few posts above with the html validator and css validator. Your nav bar isn't responsive either and I don't see the grid code in your html. Use that for the sections Skills, Experience, Role Models and Contact.